# Simple Model Data Binding in Html Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a little form that allow the user to confirm that he reallly want to delete the item, but I can't get the id on the controller...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Resources.Audit.Delete_Ask_Confirmation_Text
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.audit.id)
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash spaceAfterIcon"></i> @Resources.Audit.Delete_Ask_Confirmation_Button
            </button>
        }
```

=> In audit :

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Html

```
<div>
    <form action="/Audit/Home/Delete" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">Lore Ipsum
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="audit_Id" name="audit.Id" type="hidden" value="2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash spaceAfterIcon"></i> Please confirm the delete
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {// always null}
```

The id parameter is always null.

I've tried changing the method signature to:

```
Delete(int audit_Id), 
Delete(int id), 
Delet(string id), 
Delete(string audit_id),
 ...
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the question??

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: I cant' get the id on the controlle,r always null or Exception

Comment: this is because you have a model and an object within that which then has the ID. the naming/POSTing parameter name is not the correct one hence the model binder cannot bind the property being POST'd to the parameter in the action method. I would open up fiddler and see what the parameter is being posted as. or even open the developer toolbar and find out the DOM name of that property and then use it in the action method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use form fields and the Html helper functions you'd need to have your model as the parameter of the Delete controller method.  Having just the ID is more correct and you can make sure it is passed through by changing your form declaration and adding an object representing additional route values:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", new { id = Model.audit.id }, FormMethod.Post))}
```

You'll also be able to delete the hidden input type.

Comment: My correctness comment was more in relation to using the entire model as a parameter in your controller when you only need the id, it is more correct to pass just the id.  I'm not a lover of hidden fields anyway, it makes more sense (in my head) to pass the id in the URL in a more restful manner.

Comment: I agree with @DoctorMick, but a form may become handy when you use an anti-forgery token.

Answer (score 0):

MVC model binding handles parameters by name conversation. Your hidden input name is

```
 name="audit.Id"
```

so your action should be

```
public ActionResult Delete(audit model){
    var id = model.id;
}
```

OR

> @DoctorMick's answer.